# Cannot find module '@nestjs/typeorm'

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, nestjs, typeorm

I have installed TypeORM by using the following command:

[Github repository](https://github.com/pishguy/nest-sample)

```sh
npm i --save @nestjs/typeorm typeorm

up to date, audited 855 packages in 3s

86 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

but when I want to use `@nestjs/typeorm` it says "module not found".

`main.ts`:

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import {Logger} from '@nestjs/common';
import {NestFactory} from '@nestjs/core';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';

import {TypeOrm} from '@nestjs/typeorm';

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    await app.listen(port);
    Logger.log(`server started on ${port}`, 'Bootstrap');

}

bootstrap();
```

error:

```sh
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/typeorm' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Here is my "package.json" file:

```json
{
  "name": "---",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "---",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^1.0.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^8.0.6",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.36"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",

    ...
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

i'm not sure `Docker` cause happening this error error

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12.19.0-alpine3.9 AS development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install glob rimraf

RUN npm install --only=development

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:12.19.0-alpine3.9 as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

and `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    dev:
        container_name: nestjs_api_dev
        image: nestjs-api-dev:1.0.0
        build:
            context: .
            target: development
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        command: npm run start:debug
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
            - 9229:9229
        networks:
            - nesjs-network
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
        restart: unless-stopped
    prod:
        container_name: nestjs_api_prod
        image: nestjs-api-prod:1.0.0
        build:
            context: .
            target: production
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        command: npm run start:prod
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
            - 9229:9229
        networks:
            - nesjs-network
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
        restart: unless-stopped

networks:
    nesjs-network:
```

Comment: Not sure that it help. I compared your files with mine, seems you need install @nestjs/config instead nestjs-config;

Comment: Why do you install only development dependencies in the `DEVELOPMENT` step of your docker container?

Comment: Perhaps the first step that helps is to reproduce in the local environment to rule out the possibility that the docker environment caused this

Comment: @xiao you right, you chan checkout this repository on GitHub https://github.com/pishguy/nest-sample

Answer (score 4):

In the above Dockerfile and in the sample shared by DolDurma, during the `development` step, only the development dependencies are installed. This means that when typescript tries to find things like `@nestjs/typeorm`, `@nestjs/common` and `@nestjs/core`, along with any other packages taht are required to run the build and run the application, it can't, so it throws an error about not being able to find the package or its type declarations. The easiest solution is on [line 9 of the Dockerfile](https://github.com/pishguy/nest-sample/blob/main/Dockerfile#L9) to change from `RUN npm install --only=development` to `RUN npm install`. This will install all of the dependencies, and the docker container will be able to build properly. Then `docker compose up` will work (the instances above will not run because both bind to port 3000, but you can do `docker compose up dev` and it should be fine)

It looks like with the sample for DolDurma some extra dependencies still need to be installed, but the container does build and attempts to start with the above modification